# Call script after connecting to a wireless network

Tags: 10.04, networking, scripts

Is there a way for me to call a shell script once I connect to a specific wireless network? Reason I want to do this is I have to login to the network before I can start using it and I would like to automate this if possible.

I read this question: [Is there a way to run a script every time I connect to a specifc wireless network?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4699/is-there-a-way-to-run-a-script-every-time-i-connect-to-a-specifc-wireless-network)

But I'm really unsure as to how to use upstart to do it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Apologies for my previous answer which was the way I would have done it years ago. Seems things have changed.

It turns out that Network Manager runs ALL of the scripts in the `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/` directory (those owned by root, that are executable, that are not readable by other users, and not setuid), when a connection changes (up, down, preup, predown).

Environment variables are set and passed to this script by Network manager. You'll be interested in the CONNECTION_UUID environment variable (contains a unique string).

So, to solve your problem (execute a script when a particular wireless network is connected to):

1) find out the uuid of the wireless connection you're interested in (by looking inside the appropriate connection file in the `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/` directory).

2) write a bash (or perl, or python, or whatever) script that does what you want if the environment variable CONNECTION_UUID is a match to the uuid of the wireless network in (1) above.

3) put this script into `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/` and set the owner and permissions appropriately.

further reading: man networkmanager ( and a litte poking around the scripts in the directories mentioned above).

An example script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#####################################
# MounterBeast Script
# /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/02remotemount
# Copyright 2011 Nathan E. Williams
#
# This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
# it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
# the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
# (at your option) any later version.
#
# This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
# but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
# MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
# GNU General Public License for more details.
#
# You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
# along with this program.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
#
# Usage:
# This script must be customized for your configuration.
# By default, the script will attempt to mount a CIFS share
# when a specified MAC address is found at the network gateway,
# or over sshfs if the MAC address of the gateway is not the specified MAC.
# e.g. I mount over CIFS to the servers internal IP when at home, and
# over sshfs when away from home.
#
# id gateway mac without physically checking the sticker:
# $ arp -n -a $(ip route show 0.0.0.0/0 | awk '{print $3}') | awk '{print $4}'
#
# Testing:
# up) sudo /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/02remotemount wlan0 up
# down) sudo /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/02remotemount wlan0 down
#####################################
#
# Configuration:
#
targetmac='xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx'
mount_user='$USER'
mount_pass='pass'
internal_server_name='192.168.1.102'
external_server_name='my.dyndns.com'
share_name="music"
mount_point='/mnt/remote'
ssh_port='22'
#
# Should not need to edit below
#
gateway=$(ip route show 0.0.0.0/0 | awk '{print $3}')
mactest=$(arp -n -a $gateway | awk '{print $4}')

if [[ "$mactest" == "$targetmac" ]]
then
  case "$2" in
          up)
          sleep 5
          mount -t cifs -o username=$mount_user,password=$mount_pass //$internal_server_name/$share_name $mount_point
          ;;
          down)
          umount -l $mount_point
          ;;
  esac
else
  case "$2" in
      up)
          sleep 5
          sshfs -p $ssh_port $external_server_name:$share_name $mount_point
      ;;
      down)
          umount -l $mount_point
      ;;
  esac
fi

exit $?
```

Comment: Hey, there is nothing in /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections. Apparently, the UUID is only stored there if the connection is new (never used before). Nevertheless, I got it to work by creating a bash script in /etc/network/if-up.d. It does run the script in any wireless network I connect to though but I worked around it by doing iwconfig | grep -q "some SSID". Thanks for the bump towards the right direction though, wouldn't have figured it out without your help!

Comment: works for my gentoo installation too, thanks for the tip :)

Comment: On Ubuntu 16.04. `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/01ifupdown` executes scripts in `/etc/networking/if-*` directories

Comment: Thanks for the information. Instead of hardcoding a UUID in my script (which I want to be portable to multiple laptops), I used `grep` over the system-connections files. Works nicely. Something like `essid=$(grep -l "uuid=$CONNECTION_UUID" /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/*)` followed by `essid=$(basename $essid)`.

Comment: Is it possible to do this on a per-user basis?  I'd like to automatically select printer configuration based on currently connected network.  (https://askubuntu.com/questions/1204645/how-to-configure-cups-server-automatically-based-on-network)

Comment: @DavidFaure ```echo $(grep -Z -l "uuid=$CONNECTION_UUID" "/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/my connection.nmconnection" | xargs -0 -n1 -r basename | wc -l)```

Comment: This matches any wifi connection: ```echo $(grep -Z -l "type=wifi" /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/* | xargs -0 -n1 -r grep "uuid=$CONNECTION_UUID" | wc -l)```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if there is a way to do it with Network Manager, there is one probably but I have another solution for you. You can install Wicd :

```
sudo apt-get install wicd
```

Wicd have support directly on the gtk interface to add pre-script and post-script support to every network you can connect. Take care that Wicd will desinstall Network-Manager to work (they are both in conflict) so if something goes wrong you should download the .deb of Network-Manager or have a Live-CD/Live-USB with you.

Wicd is easy to use and quicker to connect but lack some advanced features of Network-Manager (like VPN). Here is a screenshot :

[image: Wicd]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Shell scripts in `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/` for NetworkManager is a very good idea.

There is also a Dbus method with NetworkManager, more fun, more complicated: `man nm-settings`.

A resume of shells arguments from Man page of NetworkManager about `dispatcher`:

> Each script receives two arguments, the first being the interface name
>   of the device just activated, and second an action.

Action can be: up, down, vpn-up, vpn-down, hostname, dhcp4-change, dhcp6-change .
(Release of the man page: 17 January 2012)

Here is a very simple script to restart OpenVPN after an network interface was `up`:

```
if [ "$2" = "up" ]; then  
       /etc/init.d/openvpn restart  
fi  
exit $?
```