# Set up different static IP addresses for different networks

Tags: networking, ip

I'm relatively inexperienced with networking, but I know what I want to achieve in this case. I have a computer that I physically move between two separate local networks, but when the computer is on one of those networks I want to assign a different static IP address to the machine.

One internal network is 192.168.1.0, and the other is 192.168.2.0. Therefore, I want one static IP address to be 192.168.1.x and the other to be 192.168.2.x.

Is there a way of assigning two static IPs, but with only one taking effect depending on the network its connected to? Can this be done purely in `/etc/network/interfaces`, for example?

I may well have misunderstood the situation, so if there's a different way of achieving what I want then I'm happy to hear the solution.

Comment: Did you try network manager?

Comment: I should probably mention that it's a server, so it's headless - no GUIs for me :)

Comment: You can use: Network Manager, or if you want to do it by /etc/network/interfaces than check out about virtual hosts

Comment: Take a look at [Network Configuration](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/network-configuration.html)

Comment: Sorry, I'm not prof but what I know that modern card could have more than one ip address and I'm sure that if you need to set several ip-addresses than you can do it by bash script(`ifconfig eth0:0 192.168.1.2`,`ifconfig eth0:1 192.168.2.2`) and I think it can be done by /etc/network/interfaces

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/1150429/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be better solutions (at least ones closer to what you're asking for) but here's what springs to my mind:

- Configure the DHCP servers at each location to assign your MAC address a static IP, and on the laptop, just have it automatically grab the IP from DHCP. This is by far the easiest if you have router access at each place.
- The next three are essentially the same solution as each other - split the connections up:

  - Add and use a different network card for one location.
  - Leave USB network cards on the two ethernet cables (slower than native gigabit).
  - Use two wireless connections. Network Manager can do the hard stuff automatically so you just roam from one place to another.
- Script something for when the interface comes up. I don't know what the event would really be called - but you essentially want to know when the cable is plugged in and the whole thing is ready to go. You could just have a static setup for one network and wait for when that comes up.

  - Bind in using upstart if you know the connection is there on boot, or consider this [Call script after connecting to a wireless network](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13963/call-script-after-connecting-to-a-wireless-network) if you make the connection after boot.
  - When the network is up, do some service discovery. Is the gateway where you expect it? Are there other known servers you should be able to ping?
  - If everything is correct, leave the configuration as it is, otherwise switch to the alternative network configuration. You can either manually set this up using `ifconfig` or you can have two connections set up in Network Manager and just use `nmcli` to switch which one you're on.

Out of the three, DHCP is the easiest.

Comment: I agree with your conclusion - do it at the router level. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 0):

You should create a Virtual interface and assign an IP address to it.
If you want to configure more Static IP address you need to edit the

> **/etc/network/interfaces**

and you need to enter the following lines replace **eth0** with your network interface card.

#### The primary network interface

```
auto eth0 
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.2
gateway 192.168.1.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.1.0
broadcast 192.168.1.255
```

#### The virtual network interface

To assign a second IP address to your  machine  you need to edit again  the **/etc/network/interfaces** file. The second IP is named eth0:0, the third one eth0:2 and so on... So just add them in the file:

> sudo vi /etc/network/interfaces

```
auto eth0:0
iface eth0:0 inet static
address 192.168.2.2
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.2.1
```

After entering all the details you need to restart networking services using the following command

> **sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart**