# Wait Until VPN Connection is Made before Mounting

Tags: wireless, networking, network-manager, vpn, openswan

Is there a way in /etc/fstab that I can wait for the VPN connection to be made, and then mount the network drives?

Comment: you can of course combine it in one script; connect to VPN and mount (immediately after connection is established). Is that what you want to achieve?

Comment: Well... connect happens when the machine starts, so no need to automate that part of it...  once that connection is established though, that's when I want to mount the drive(s)

Answer (score 1):

if you use the [noauto option](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab) in the fstab line the filesystem will NOT be automatically mounted at start-up. You can then later mount the filesystem explicitly with a [dispatcher script](https://askubuntu.com/a/14139/34029) for NetworkManager which is automatically executed when the VPN is successfully connected.

Comment: gotcha...  think you may take a gander: http://askubuntu.com/questions/458266/l2tp-ipsec-vpn-disconnect-issues