# Remounting SMB shares when changing between wifi/wired networks

Tags: networking, wireless, mount, cifs, smb

I've been battling with this for a while with mixed results. I frequently move my laptop between it's dock (wired) and my couch (wireless). Anytime I switch networks, I have to manually run "sudo mount -a" to get my shares back. It's not a huge deal, but I'd like to fix it.

Here's my fstab right now:

```
//192.168.0.50/backup /media/backup cifs iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm 0 0 
//192.168.0.50/videos /media/videos cifs iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm 0 0 
//192.168.0.50/dvr /media/dvr cifs iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm 0 0 
//192.168.0.50/apps /media/apps cifs iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm 0 0 
//192.168.0.50/music /media/music cifs iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm 0 0 
//192.168.0.50/temp /media/temp cifs iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm 0 0
```

Ideas?

Bonus info: when I switch to the wired connection, I have to manually  use the network indicator icon to disable networking, and re-enable it.

Comment: To run a script after a connection has been established, look here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/13963/call-script-after-connecting-to-a-wireless-network

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add script in `/etc/network/if-up.d/` and when `wlan0` go `up` call script witch will do `sudo mount -a`.

Make script called `script` with execute `permissions 755`

`sudo nano /etc/network/if-up.d/script`

```
# Check for specific interface if desired
[ "$IFACE" != "wlan0" ] || exit 0
# Do something
sudo mount -a
```

Comment: If I drop the [ "$IFACE" != "wlan0" ] || exit 0 line, will it run this everytime a connection goes up? I need to do it when eth0 goes up too.

Comment: Will  do every time when wlan0 go up. For eth0 create one more script on the same plaxe. Only change interface name from wlan0 to eth0.