# sysctl unable to apply settings on boot

Tags: networking, server

I followed a tutorial similar to this https://www.niftiestsoftware.com/2011/08/28/making-all-network-traffic-for-a-linux-user-use-a-specific-network-interface/

And started noticing that after a reboot the sysctl system settings weren't applied anymore, specifically these settings from `/etc/sysctl.d/999-vpn.conf` (also tried putting them in the `99-sysctl.conf` file):

```
net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter = 2
net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter = 2
net.ipv4.conf.enx002427fe2be7.rp_filter = 2
```

This is the error in my syslog:

```
systemd-sysctl[289]: Couldn't write '2' to 'net/ipv4/conf/enx002427fe2be7/rp_filter', ignoring: No such file or directory
```

`enx002427fe2be7` is the network interface name from my USB Network adapter that I use, and I'm guessing that the reason this fails is maybe because it hasnt been initialized yet when the `sysctl` command runs.

So to fix this I tried an `upstart` script, but even with `exec sleep 60 && sysctl --system` this didn't seem to work.

Manually running `sysctl --system` fixes it, but I'd rather have this automated.

What would be a proper way to fix this?

Using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Server edition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few things come to my mind:

1. ubuntu 16.04 uses `systemd` by default instead of `upstart`. So you could try to write a `systemd` unit instead of an `upstart` script
2. If you use `/etc/network/interfaces` to manage your network, you could add a line like the following to your interface:

   ```
   up sysctl net.ipv4.conf.enx002427fe2be7.rp_filter=2
   ```

   and remove the corresponding line from your `/etc/sysctl.d/999-vpn.conf` file.

   If you use `NetworkManager` there is `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/` where you can put scripts to execute after a connection is made. Of course in your script you should check that the interface that is brought up is actually your USB adapter.

   ```
   if [ "$1" == 'enx002427fe2be7' ] && [ "$2" == 'up' ] ; then
       sysctl net.ipv4.conf.enx002427fe2be7.rp_filter=2
   fi
   ```

   Alternatively you could put that script in `/etc/network/if-up.d/`. This should work for both, `ifupdown` and `NetworkManager`. (Source: https://askubuntu.com/a/14139/726877). In that case you don't need the `up` line in `/etc/network/interfaces`.

   ```
   if [ "$IFACE" == 'enx002427fe2be7' ] ; then
       sysctl net.ipv4.conf.enx002427fe2be7.rp_filter=2
   fi
   ```

   These are just different ways to do the same thing: add the `sysctl` setting for the network adapter when the network adapter is brought up and therefore available but no sooner.

Comment: Thanks! very detailed and informative answer, it worked perfectly as well. I'll award the bounty when the site lets me